# SQL less/greater comparison between booleans produces unexpected results

Tags: sql, mysql, postgresql, sqlite, mariadb

Why do most(all?) SQL Databases give:

```
SELECT FALSE < FALSE;      -- FALSE / 0   Ok
SELECT TRUE < FALSE;       -- FALSE / 0   Ok

SELECT NOT(FALSE) < FALSE; -- TRUE / 1    What?
SELECT NOT(TRUE) < FALSE;  -- TRUE / 1    What??
```

And just do double check:

```
SELECT NOT(TRUE) = FALSE;  -- TRUE / 1    Ok
SELECT NOT(FALSE) = TRUE;  -- TRUE / 1    Ok
```

In Postgres, I can also check:

```
SELECT pg_typeof(TRUE), pg_typeof(NOT(FALSE));
  -- boolean | boolean
```

I've tried this with PostgreSQL, SQLite3 and MariaDB, and all agree on the same unexpected result.
**What am I missing?**

Comment: `NOT` is not a function, it's a Boolean operator.

Comment: Please read https://mariadb.com/kb/en/operator-precedence/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`NOT` and `<` are operators. Let's take a look at operator precedence:

[image]

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/operator-precedence.html

From here we can see that `<` precedes `NOT` in priority, so

```
NOT(FALSE) < FALSE
```

is equivalent to

```
NOT(FALSE < FALSE)
```

and since `FALSE` is not smaller than itself, the inner expression is 0, that is, it's `FALSE` and its negation is `TRUE`.

Whereas, if you enforce the operator order you preferred:

```
(NOT(FALSE)) < FALSE
```

then you will get the result you expected:

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @GeorgRichter the code is already given above the image. The image is proof of the result. If I remove the image, then I remove the proof of the results. Images of code are unhelpful. But if the code is given as text and the image is proving that it's working, then it should be okay in my opinion.

Comment: While everyone talks about inclusion, you exclude visually impaired people from the discussion. Not to talk about the CO2 footprint of an image compared to a few copy/paste characters.

Comment: @GeorgRichter you should switch off your computer if you are worried about carbon emissions... But then how could you share your ideologically-driven wisdom? And if I exclude visually impaired people by sharing an image, then I exclude analphabets by typing letters, mentally impaired people by sharing thoughts, etc. I do not intend to constantly worry about excluding people from a discussion for the sole reason that I share a proof of something. If a visually impaired person can grasp the text, then he or she will get the answer, except for the proof that it's working.

Comment: @Lajos Arpad: Sorry, I can't follow you. Like visually impaired people also analphabets use text to speech. So they have exactly the same problem: Text inside an image.

Comment: @hobby_programmer I do not think this is very complex. I just provided a clear disproof of the validity of mister Richter's criticism. If we are fixated with "inclusion" to the point of destroying our ability of sharing thoughts, then we should not write a single letter in questions, answers or comments for being worried that some people are unable to read it. I did not get into it earlier, but I find it **very** hard to imagine that a visually impaired person would work as a programmer or follow SO questions. But, if a person has this problem and visits the site,

Comment: @hobby_programmer and we presume that the person is able to grasp the text and we assume further that the person actually understands what we are speaking about, then the person will understand the answer even without seeing the images, but the images are providing proof. And, to be very frank: if I was visually impaired, I would not expect those who are not visually impaired to censor everything I cannot see just to accomodate me. And, if we are so obsessed with "inclusion", then why don't we include people who like to **see** proofs?

Comment: @hobby_programmer Freedom of expression was (past tense) a basic human right. I have no intention to exclude anyone (quite absurd that in this world I even have to clarify that) from the discussion, but I reject the idea that I should decrease the quality of my answer by **removing** the proof of an actual experiment for the sake if visually impaired people. If I would have only shared an image, then it would have been valid to criticize my answer for it. But since I have given the code and the explanation as text and only attached an image as an illustration and proof that what I am

Comment: @hobby_programmer actually speaking about actually works, I find mister Richter's criticism to be nitpicking and ideologically driven. And I am very generous with assuming fanaticism on his part, because otherwise I would have to seriously consider the possibility that it was written in ill faith. Where is the support for free expression both in content and form?

Comment: @hobby_programmer and, quite conveniently, you ignored my other argument: mentally impaired people will not be able to grasp any of our thoughts. And, by the way, analphabets who are deaf at the same time (intersection, as the wokes call it) will not be able to interpret any text, even if they use text-to-speech and they would **only** see the images I have shared. Now let's ignore for a second that an analphabet would even have trouble in visiting this very page or **writing** code.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know exactly how `NOT(FALSE)` is evaluating, but `NOT` is not a function.  If you want to not a boolean literal, then the parentheses should be around the entire expression, i.e. use `(NOT FALSE)` instead of `NOT(FALSE)`.  Consider:

```sql
SELECT (NOT FALSE) < FALSE; -- 0, same as TRUE < FALSE
SELECT (NOT TRUE) < FALSE;  -- 0, same as FALSE < FALSE
```

Comment: Tim, `FALSE` is 0 and `NOT(someboolean)` is 1 - someboolean, so `NOT(FALSE)` is evaluated as 1, which stands for `TRUE`. The reason for the behavior experienced in the question is operator precedence.

Comment: @LajosArpad I got it.  So I sort of gave a right correction with an incomplete explanation.

Comment: Exactly. I upvoted your answer for being correct.

Answer (score 5):

My answer is about SQLite (but I suspect that the same applies to other dbs).

An expression like:

```
NOT(FALSE) < FALSE;
```

is evaluated as:

```
NOT((FALSE) < FALSE);
```

because [the operator `<` has higher precedence over the operator `NOT`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#operators_and_parse_affecting_attributes).
Since `(FALSE) < FALSE` evaluates to `FALSE`, the result of the expression is `TRUE`.